# Execute Java Thread in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to implement a Java Thread which is used to monitor dashboard for ID and clicks them if they are present. Normal code exception should not be interrupted. I tried this:

```
public static Thread handleAlert(final WebDriver driver)
    {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.addAll("......");
        
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println("Checking dialog .... ");
                        List<WebElement> lis = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));

                        for(WebElement li : lis)
                        {
                            String id =li.getAttribute("id");

                            if(list.contains(id)){
                                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! found " + id);
                                driver.findElement(By.id(id)).click();
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("dialog Accepted. ");
                    }catch(NoAlertPresentException n){
                        System.out.println("No dialog Present.  ");
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return thread;
    }



    @Test
    @Timeout(value = 60, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void verifyTest() {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        handleAlert(driver).start();
        ... do some Selenium logic here...
       
        handleAlert(driver).stop();
   }
```

The code works well when I want to intercept buttons with unique ID.
But as you can see Java Thread is just started. I need to execute it in parallel with the test case. Is it possible the Thread to run in parallel and check of unique button ID without interrupting the JUnit test case?

Comment: Those constantly polling driver calls will not happen in parallel.  They'll happen in some unpredictable order... in between other webdriver calls.  It'll still be one sequential timeline.  You should make your calls before and/or after other calls.  Are you dealing with some kind of random alert?

Comment: Any solution for the problem?

Comment: maybe try using webdriver event listener:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html

Comment: I tried it and it works but only for the first dialog window. I need to click a series of buttons which appear into dialog windows.

Comment: doesn't really sound random.  You should be able to figure out the proper sequence of actions.

Comment: maybe with multiple try-catch logic?

Comment: sure... DWMS  (Do What Makes Sense)